# How to identify name of parent app in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have one main app running in elixir, this main app has few dependencies and one of the dependency is an app itself. I am trying to identify the name of the main app from within the dependency app.

When I try calling [`:application.get_application/0`](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#get_application-0) from the dependent app I get the name of the dependent app. How do I get the name of the main or parent app?

Comment: 1. Is it a compile time or runtime? 2. What do you mean by “one of the dependency is an app itself” as it’s impossible in OTP. 3. Main app means umbrella project?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin,  **What do you mean by “one of the dependency is an app itself” as it’s impossible in OTP.** -- Is that right? From the [OTP Application docs](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html): *Notice that all applications have dependencies to **at least** Kernel and STDLIB.*  And, if I look up STDLIB, the [STDLIB docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/STDLIB_app.html) say: *The STDLIB application.*

Comment: @7stud: Hell no, read the source if you don't know. https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/stdlib.app.src#L109 Don't guess.

Comment: @7stud: If you are curious, no, kernel doesn't have any dependency https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/kernel/src/kernel.app.src#L146

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil,  *kernel doesn't have any dependency*-- How is that relevant?  The statement I was questioning was: *It's impossible in OTP for an app to have a dependency that is an app.*  As a counter example to that statement I posted some quotes from the OTP docs, which say that all apps depend on STDLIB and that STDLIB is an app.

Answer (score 4):

NB: I suspect this is an instance of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/188965), and that what you're trying to do can be accomplished better in another way.  In general, an application should interact explicitly with applications that it depends on, not with applications that depend on it.

That said, you can get a list of applications that depend on your application:

```
myapp = :my_application
apps_that_depend_on_me =
  for {app,_,_} <- Application.loaded_applications(),
    deps = Application.spec(app)[:applications],
    myapp in deps do
      app
  end

IO.inspect(apps_that_depend_on_me)
```

In principle many applications can depend on your application, so there isn't necessarily a single "parent app".